# UIButton location while zooming a UIScrollView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a "world view," so to speak, that consists of a large, zoomable area on a UIScrollView.  I want several buttons to retain their world location when I pinch to zoom, much like pins in Google Maps do.  The code I have been trying (I have been coding for hours, but I think it sounds right...although I may be just burned out) is:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint center = button.center;
    center.y = center.y * scrollView.zoomScale;
    center.x = center.x * scrollView.zoomScale;
    button.center = center;
    NSLog(@"Button coordinates are %f, %f, zoomScale is %f", button.center.x, button.center.y, scrollView.zoomScale);
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by setting the CGPoint 'center' only once, on view load, and then calculating a new center point based off of the original location.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint newCenter = center; //center is set at load time, and only once
    newCenter.y = center.y * scrollView.zoomScale; //new center is calculated on original position
    newCenter.x = center.x * scrollView.zoomScale;
    button.center = newCenter;

    NSLog(@"Button coordinates are %f, %f, zoomScale is %f", button.center.x, button.center.y, scrollView.zoomScale);
}
```

Sorry about mistagging the question, Peter.

Comment: How did you set the "center" during load view?  I am trying to do the same thing I think. I have a map that is 500x500 and pixs that are 32x32  I want to keep the pins at 32x32 and make sure they point to the same location after zooming in.  I am having a hard time getting this to work.

Comment: Overlay a second UIScrollView on your zooming one, and forward touches from that one into the one you want to zoom.  Have the second one (the zooming one) return a view in the -(UIScrollView*)viewFroZoomingInScrollView delegate method, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all the maths yourself. UIScrollView's base class, UIView, has four methods for converting between coordinate systems, which in the case of a UIScrollView take zooming and panning into account:

```
– convertPoint:toView:
– convertPoint:fromView:
– convertRect:toView:
– convertRect:fromView:
```

See the UIView documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html